# Care Packages for college students

Tags: discussion, survey

Questions: Parents
Would you purchase a care package for your child?
What price range would you consider?
How much customization would you want?
How often would you send a care package?
What kind of items would you want your college student to receive?

I'm working on an assignment for school where we create a business model for a care package for students to engage them in their new town/community rather than just giving them toiletries.   Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'll take part in your research!

1) Yes, I would buy care packages for my college student.
2) I would think in the $25 - $35 range.
3) A lot! I'd probably expect a list (maybe a rotating assortment) to choose from.
4) Once a month, I think.
5) An assortment of some junk and mostly healthy snacks, to be honest. Junk can be chocolate anything, and crispy carbohydrates (stressed-out people often crave salty/crispy/high-carb snacks.) Healthy could be nut mixes, nut butter, crackers, pumpkin seeds, maybe some good fruit juices, jerky, spicy popcorn, trail mix, no-sugar-added dried fruit, maybe protein bars, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When my oldest started college as a freshman, we sent "care packages" every month or so. We included some of her favorite treats form Trader Joe's, as there isn't one in Missoula. She's very musical, so I sent her a nice ukulele. That was a hit. As she progressed in school and made friends, we sent fewer packages.

Your business model is going to be competing with Amazon.